# M.2 4G Sierra Module ( Dell )

Tags: mobile-broadband, 4g

i have a M.2 4g Sierra AirPrime module. It did say it was a replacement for a range of Dell models, so, my question is, will this work with Ubuntu or will it only work with the Dell models. ?

i can pick it up on the system, but i cannot get it to work.  also, when i looked at the device through the terminal, it says in the system settings section, the plugin is Dell.  it also only shows up as 2G and 3G.

My guess is that it will only work with Dell, but any advice would be great.  i tried to post an image of it, but i am unable to embed images..